# Rewrite not working for some url in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

For some URL my htaccess not working as it should. I just want to rewrite the extension of the file like php to html. But it's not working. When I am typing URL like "http://www.example.com/myfile.php" and "http://www.example.com/myfile.html" both url are working. But i just want to rewrite myfile.php to myfile.html.

My htaccess rewrite rule is :-

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset Last-Modified
Header unset ETag

RewriteRule ^myfile.html$ myfile.php [QSA,L]

ServerSignature Off
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+myfile\.php(\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /myfile.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^myfile\.html$ /myfile.php [NC,L]
```

The first rule takes care of redirecting to `myfile.html` if the user tries to access `myfile.php` directly.